# Scala - transform a XML literal into a string without newlines

Tags: xml, scala

For more clarification in a XML structure I will write every tag in a single line.

Unfortunately the result contains (after transforming to text) more than one line, so the assertion failed. I need the whole result as a single line without newlines

```
val row = <row>
            <fromSubsystem>02</fromSubsystem>
            <toSubsystem>01</toSubsystem>
            <action>E013</action>
            <comment>return to customer</comment>
          </row>

println("==> " + row.text)  

assert(row.text == "0201E013return to customer")   

==> 
             02
             01
             E013
             return to customer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:146)
```

Thanks in advance for an elegant solution!

Pongo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
row.child.map(_.text.trim).mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a regexp?

```
assert(row.text.replaceAll("\n[ ]+","") == "0201E013") 

//or just "\n +" in replaceAll
```

If you don't like regexp and dont care about spaces in tag's text you can do something like this:

```
assert(row.text.filterNot(Set(' ','\n')) == "0201E013")
```

Comment: Nice, but if in the xml structure a tag like this:              <comment>return to customer</comment> the result is: 0201E013returntocustomer

Comment: @Twistleton oh, then I have to be more specific in regexp. I've updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your assertion to this:

```
assert(row.text.split('\n').map(_.trim).mkString == "0201E013return to customer")
```